# MongoDB preserving newlines inside objects

Tags: mongodb, mongo-shell

I'm new to MongoDB and following a tutorial to get used to the shell and basic MongoDB commands. In the tutorial, the instructor typed out an insertOne command inside the IDE, then pasted it inside the Mongo shell. When they did it, the object seemed to collapse itself, getting rid of new lines. When I did it, it seems to have preserved the structure that it had when I typed it out in my IDE.

Here's how I typed out the insertOne command, which I then pasted into the shell:

```
db.products.insertOne({
  _id: 2,
  name: 'Pencil',
  price: 0.80,
  stock: 12,
  reviews: [
    {
      authorName: 'Harry',
      rating: 5,
      review: 'Really made me write!'
    }
  ]
})
```

And here's what came out when I queried all the items in the collection. The 'Pen' one, I had just entered all on one line because it was short. [image: one one-liner, one multiline]

1. Which way would be more normal for a document to be stored? It's more readable of course for every key-value pair to be on one line, but I assume it takes up more space or something to be stored this way
2. Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are conflating how the document is stored in the database, and how it is presented on your screen by the application/driver/shell/IDE.

MongoDB stores documents using [BSON](https://bsonspec.org).  The document shown would be stored as (hex notation):

```
00000000: 9f00 0000 015f 6964 0000 0000 0000 0000  ....._id........
00000010: 4002 6e61 6d65 0007 0000 0050 656e 6369  @.name.....Penci
00000020: 6c00 0170 7269 6365 009a 9999 9999 99e9  l..price........
00000030: 3f01 7374 6f63 6b00 0000 0000 0000 2840  ?.stock.......(@
00000040: 0472 6576 6965 7773 0055 0000 0003 3000  .reviews.U....0.
00000050: 4d00 0000 0261 7574 686f 724e 616d 6500  M....authorName.
00000060: 0600 0000 4861 7272 7900 0172 6174 696e  ....Harry..ratin
00000070: 6700 0000 0000 0000 1440 0272 6576 6965  g........@.revie
00000080: 7700 1600 0000 5265 616c 6c79 206d 6164  w.....Really mad
00000090: 6520 6d65 2077 7269 7465 2100 0000 00    e me write!....
```

There are no newlines stored there at all.

When queries, those bytes are what would be sent across the wire, anything actually displayed to you is the interpretation of those bytes by the application on the client side.